# Am I allowed to share YouTube dataset ?

Tags: youtube-api, dataset, sharing

I have used YouTube API to crawl publicly available content of the website (the comments on the videos) to develop a dataset for research purposes.

The dataset is completely anonymous and all the use ids and other information that can lead to identification of users are removed.

I was wondering whether I am allowed to share the dataset with other researchers or not? or what are the conditions to do so?

Thank you, Maral

Comment: If you cannot share the dataset, share the source code on github, without your api keys of course. So who ever wants it can run the crawl using their own api. The only cost will be run time for them. Besides, each researcher will look for some category of videos so their comments will match the text type they wanna research on. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the [YouTube Terms of Service](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms) as well as the [YouTube API terms of service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms). I am not a lawyer and cannot interpret the terms for you, but it sounds like you would be dangerously close to item 4 of the Prohibitions section:

> Your API Client will not, and You will not encourage or create
>   functionality for Your users or other third parties to:
>
> sell, lease, lend, convey, redistribute, or sublicense to any third
>   party all or any portion of the YouTube API or API Data (except that
>   You may distribute and display the YouTube audiovisual content and
>   accompanying metadata to Your users through Your API Client in a
>   manner that complies with this Agreement);

Check with your organization's legal counsel for final say.

Answer (score 0):

What you were thinking of doing could not have been that illegal, probably not illegal at all, as researchers at Simon Fraser University in Canada have done just that :

http://netsg.cs.sfu.ca/youtubedata/

They just said "academic use only".

From [this](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-legal-to-crawl-YouTube-videos-for-research-purposes-say-a-video-dataset) Quora reference it also mentions not to share such material for commercial gain. Anyway, if you put it out there somewhere post a link so we can have a look.